# AWS Amplify List Resource Dependencies

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

Is there a way using the `amplify` cli to list the dependencies of a resource? For example, I want to see resource dependent on my `auth` module created through amplify.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is [such command in Amplify-CLI](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli) but you can definitely know a category dependencies by looking at `dependsOn` block in the [`amplify/backend/backend-config.json` file](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/quickstart#custom-cloudformation-stacks).

This is an example of auth category looks like in `amplify/backend/backend-config.json` file with an AWS lambda function/[custom message trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html) as a dependency:

[image]